# Time Buckets to group the data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, bucket

I would like to have a certain time buckets and then find the difference of each time bucket to analyse.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'A-1 A-1 A-1 A-1 A-1 A-1'.split(),
                   'Date':'23.10.2021 23.10.2021 23.10.2021 23.10.2021 23.10.2021 23.10.2021'.split(),
                   'Time': '06:05:31 06:11:13 06:19:22 06:25:03 06:33:12 06:44:05'.split(),
                   'Cumulative': '12 17 19 23 29 38'.split()})
print(df)
```

out:

```
     A        Date      Time Cumulative
0  A-1  23.10.2021  06:05:31         12
1  A-1  23.10.2021  06:11:13         17
2  A-1  23.10.2021  06:19:22         19
3  A-1  23.10.2021  06:25:03         23
4  A-1  23.10.2021  06:33:12         29
5  A-1  23.10.2021  06:44:05         38
```

What I'd like to have is ceiling the hours by 15 mins intervals and find the difference of each,
1st Step:

```
     A        Date      Time Cumulative      TimeBuckets
0  A-1  23.10.2021  06:05:31         12         06:15:00 
1  A-1  23.10.2021  06:11:13         17         06:15:00 
2  A-1  23.10.2021  06:19:22         19         06:30:00 
3  A-1  23.10.2021  06:25:03         23         06:30:00 
4  A-1  23.10.2021  06:33:12         29         06:45:00 
5  A-1  23.10.2021  06:44:05         38         06:45:00
```

and in final stage as a different dataframe, difference of each minimum and maximum value for each time bucket would be written:

```
     A         Diff   TimeBuckets
0  A-1            5      06:15:00  
1  A-1            4      06:30:00    
2  A-1            8      06:45:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`dt.ceil`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) and [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.assign(Cumulative=df['Cumulative'].astype(int),
           TimeBuckets=pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.ceil('15min').dt.time
          )
   .groupby('TimeBuckets', as_index=False)
   .agg({'A': 'first', 'Cumulative': lambda x: x.max()-x.min()})
)
```

output:

```
  TimeBuckets    A  Cumulative
0    06:15:00  A-1           5
1    06:30:00  A-1           4
2    06:45:00  A-1           9
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I have 2 more questions:
1) I also would like to see if there is no data between any timebuckets, it should be shown in the cumulative column as zero.
2) there is a problem for day changes, because for the data of  >= 23:45:00 will be ceiled to 00:00:00 for the same date, but it should be 00:00:00 for Day+1.

hope that I expressed my question well

Comment: @acme.py better provide a reproducible sample of the data, and if this changes too much the data/logic open a new question to keep this one "clean"

Comment: okay, thx @mozway. let  me open a new question, because I cannot copy+paste the sample code due to having character limit in the comment section

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71351427/17933136 
btw, I've posted it as another question @mozway. is it possible for you to check?